# Enumerable.Max with a selector lambda function

Tags: vb.net, lambda, ienumerable

I have a list of `Column` custom class objects.

`Column` class has a `Position` property.

Each column in the list has a different position (currently 1, 2, 3, 4)

I want to find the rightmost column throgh a `Max` on the `Position` property:

```
Enumerable.Max(Of ExcelColumn)(Me.Columns, Function(c) c.Position)
```

or

```
Me.Columns.Max(Function(c) c.Position)
```

Both always return `0`, don't understand why. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
Class Column
    Public Property Position As Int32
End Class

Dim columns As New List(Of Column) From {
    New Column With {.Position = 1}, New Column With {.Position = 2}, New Column With {.Position = 3}, New Column With {.Position = 4}
}
Dim maxColPos As Int32 = columns.Max(Function(c) c.Position)

Console.Write(maxColPos) ' will output 4
```

By the way, this will return repeating zeros and hence `maxColPos=0`:

```
Dim columns As New List(Of Column) From {
    New Column, New Column, New Column, New Column
}
```

becaue 0 is the [default value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for an unitialized `Int32` field.

Comment: `Dim maxCol As Int32` was implied. For some undisclosed reason it always returns 0. I've checked `position` *s* at runtime and they are correct.

Comment: @Teejay: It returns 0 if it is not initialized since that is the default value. If i would omit the `{.Position = 1}` parts above, i would also get repeating zeros.

Comment: Me STUPID!!! Forgot a `Return` in the `Get` statement:
`Public ReadOnly Property RightMostCol As Int32
        Get
            Me.Columns.Max(Function(c) c.Position)
        End Get
    End Property`